# Can I say “since $\operatorname{Char}R\ne2$ then $b=0$, hence $a=b=c=0$”?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to show that since the set $\{x_1, x_2, x_3\}$ in a vector space $V$ over a division ring $R$ is linearly independent, then the set $\{x_1+x_2, x_2+x_3, x_1+x_3\}$ is also linearly independent in the vector space $V$ if and only if $\operatorname{Char}R\ne2$. $R$ is a division ring.

Actually I am trying to prove this in this way:

Let $a, b , c$ be scalars such that

$$a(x_1+x_2)+ b(x_2+x_3)+c(x_1+x_3)=0$$

which is equivalent to

$$(a+c)x_1 + (a+b)x_2 + (b+c)x_3=0.$$

Then, since this set is linearly independent, we get

$$(a+c)=(a+b)=(b+c)=0.$$

By subtracting, I get $2b=0$.

My questions are:

1. Can I say that “since $\operatorname{Char}R\ne 2$ then $b=0$, hence $a=b=c=0$, therefore $\{x_1+x_2, x_2+x_3, x_1+x_3\}$ is also linearly independent? if true, how to show that $\operatorname{Char}R\ne2$ can imply that $b=0$?
2. What happens if $\operatorname{Char}R=2$?

Please advise me for this.

Comment: Have you tried showing these things for a field first, just to see what happens there?

Comment: Actually yes, i did it, but the result unsatisfied

Comment: In fact, they are linearly independent if and only if $2$ is not a zero divisor in $R$. Further, $2$ is a zero divisor if and only if the characteristic is positive and even.

Comment: @anon:  but are we not correct in assuming $char(R)$ is prime, since $R$ is a division ring?

Comment: @RobertLewis Yes - my reading passed over that condition. Doesn't hurt to know more general information I suppose.

Answer (score 2):

Note that in Characteristic 2 $$(x_1+x_2)+(x_2+x_3)+(x_1+x_3)=2(x_1+x_2+x_2)=0$$

which is a dependence between the three vectors in the second set, and which can also be written $$(x_1+x_2)+(x_2+x_3)=(x_1+x_3)$$

Comment: can you show the prove to show that if the Char $R$ not equals $2$ will imply $2b=0$?

Comment: @alexa You mean that in that case $2b = 0$ implies $b = 0$? This should really be obvious from the definition of characteristic and the fact the we are working over an integral domain.

Comment: In char $2$ we have $1+1=0$ so that $2b=b+b=1b+1b=(1+1)b=0b=0$

Answer (score 0):

The proof should be the same for a division ring or a field. Given a linear relation $  a_1  (x_1+x_2)+a_2(x_1+x_3)+a_3(x_2+x_3)=0$, we have the relation $ (a_1+a_2)x_1+ (a_1+a_3)x_2 + (a_2+a_3)x_3=0$ so by linear independence we have $a_1=-a_2$ and so on. Now you can just plug in these equalities into our first equation to get $a_1,a_2,a_3=0$ .

Maybe you are already there, but if the point you are stuck on is why does $2a_1=0$ imply $a_1=0$, then consider $a_1 \ne 0$ then since $R$ is a division ring, it is also a domain (same proof as commutative works) so then $2=0$ and we win.

For the other direction see the other answer

Comment: @egreg, can you make clearly the last proof of you? I am not really clear about that..where is $2a_1=0$ imply $a_1=0$, then consider $a_1≠0$ then since $R$ is a division ring, it is also a domain (same proof as commutative works) so then $2=0$ and we win..because you said that also in the end $2=0$..thanks

Comment: We are assuming our $R$ is not characteristic $2$ so $2=0$ is a contradiction.